# SSRS Report Builder DropDown Menus

Tags: reporting-services, report, dropdown, builder

Can we create a drop down by getting some fields from Dataset 1 and Dataset2.
That means,

DataSet1

- MatterType
- InjuryType
- MatterNumber

DataSet2

- WorkType
- Address

I want to create a drop down list by getting values from MatterType,InjuryType,WorkType and Address
from datasets in SSRS or Microsoft Report Builder, Is it Possible ?

Comment: Do you mean as a parameter drop down?